# More clearer assigning variables to current index of unsigned char array

Tags: c++

The first four variables are `unsigned char` with value `0` or `1`.

The `messageType` is `unsigned char`, example: `48`.

I was wondering if there is some way to do this code more clearer.

I am trying to not use any library.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> packet(2);

packet.at(0) |= (retain) << 0;
packet.at(0) |= (qosLevel >> 0) << 1;
packet.at(0) |= (qosLevel >> 1) << 2;
packet.at(0) |= (dupFlag) << 3;
packet.at(0) |= ((messageType >> 4) & 1) << 4;
packet.at(0) |= ((messageType >> 5) & 1) << 5;
packet.at(0) |= ((messageType >> 6) & 1) << 6;
packet.at(0) |= ((messageType >> 7) & 1) << 7;
```

Comment: Maybe bitfields?  Although IIRC the ordering of bitfields when copying a whole object like that is implementation-defined, so it won't work if you're planning to serialize the data over the network.

Comment: `std::bitset` matybe

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to mention I don't want to use any library.

Comment: @JohnDoe Not even STL ? I think you're already using it with `std::vector`.

Comment: Because with pure `unsigned char` this code won't work. I mean I use library only when it is necessary. I am sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Write a function that sets individual bits or ranges of bits from arbitrary sources to arbitrary destinations and call that multiple times. That would make it clear what you are doing. Or am I understanding the question wrong?

Comment: You're trying to set multibit values using single bit operations without masking.  That won't work.  You can use `(qosLevel & 3) << 1` to set both bits.

Comment: @walnut I will have to. I just thought my code is coded complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the variables don't contain any extra bits then you can write:

```
    unsigned char packet[2] = { 0 };
    packet[0] |= retain;
    packet[0] |= qosLevel << 1;
    packet[0] |= dupFlag << 3;
    packet[0] |= messageType;
```

Alternatively you could mask out any potential extra bits:

```
    unsigned char packet[2] = { 0 };
    packet[0] |= retain & 1;
    packet[0] |= (qosLevel & 3) << 1;
    packet[0] |= (dupFlag & 1) << 3;
    packet[0] |= messageType & 0xf0;
```